# files vanished in target directory after mv

Tags: command-line, bash

I executed the following command, intending to move the file into a subdirectory.

```
sudo mv myFile.jar hexara/*
```

Should I have used the following syntax instead?

```
sudo mv myFile.jar hexara
```

or?

```
sudo mv myFile.jar hexara/
```

Sudo is being invoked because I am in an area where the account does not have write privileges. I'm using SSH to work in a remote server.

In any event, after this, an `ls` of the subfolder hexara shows that the file I moved is not there and that many files in the hexara directory are now missing. Previously there were three subfolders and an index.htm file, but now only one subfolder remains.

Did my malformed mv command cause the files to disappear, or should I suspect some other form of glitch or a different error was made? There were intervening commands--I navigated to another area and returned before cd'ing into hexara and discovering the loss, and made a copy of the CLI if that is of any help.

Is something like this recoverable?

An `ls -al` showed the following:

```
phil@ladonax:/var/lib/jetty9/webapps/hexara$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 jetty adm 4096 Jun 30 10:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 jetty adm 4096 Jun 30 10:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 jetty adm 4096 Jun 30 10:26 VSL
```

VSL, by the way, has 14 files in it, so I don't know where the above "total 12" comes from. The hexara directory might have had three subfolders and only one file in it before the loss. But I don't see why this would have turned up in the "total" but not appear in the accompanying listing.

Fortunately I have backup files of this directory. But I'm really puzzled as to what happened.
Am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Yes, there is a task on the queue to upgrade Jetty but I assume that would not have any pertinence to this question.

EDIT: I discovered that all the files in the hexara subdirectory were moved into hexara/VSL. Any thoughts as to why `../webapps $ mv myFile.jar hexara/*` would cause files in `../webapps/hexara` to be moved into `../webapps/hexara/VSL`?

Comment: When the last arg of mv is a dir, all the previous args (files) get moved there.  You can simply move them back up a level (mv file .. ).

Comment: If you're not sure about `mv` usage, it takes only seconds to create a couple empty testfiles and test directories to verify that your syntax does what you expect. Be sure before using `sudo`. "*Hmmm...let's make sure first*" is the motto of a true professional.

Comment: @user535733 my method is to do an `ls` since that will show all files the `mv` will move :)

Comment: mv is weird. I think I am going to go back to using cp and deleting the original after verifying the copy was made correctly.

Comment: Ah, learned that this was due to an unexpected * expansion. Maybe mv isn't as weird as I thought.

Comment: For (1) and (2), your question was added to the "Hot Network Questions" which usually means that your question gets a lot of views and lot of upvotes from users from *other* Stack Exchange sites, [often without any relation whatever to question quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238420/prevent-questions-on-the-hot-list-from-being-upvoted-by-casual-visitors-only-re).

Comment: As for (3) and (4), that's the *point* of closing as duplicates. Duplicates aren't automatically deleted, they instead lead users searching for the same thing in different ways to the right area.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about the distinction between "closing" and "deleting". I think that leaving this question up and funneling replies to the first iteration is reasonable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo mv myFile.jar hexara/*
```

this will move myFile.jar into `./hexara/VSL/`. Proof:

```
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ ls
hexara  myFile.jar
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ pwd
/home/rinzwind/tmp/tmp/tmp
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ mv myFile.jar hexara/*
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ ls hexara/VSL/
myFile.jar
```

To revert do

```
cd hexara/VSL/
mv myFile.jar ../../
```

Or to fix (since you want it in ./hexara/)

```
cd hexara/VSL/
mv myFile.jar ../
```

---

The `*` gets expanded so when there are 2 or more directories everything moves to the last directory.

```
mv myFile.jar hexara/*
```

does

```
mv myFile.jar hexara/VSL hexara/WSL
```

Proof:

```
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ ls -ltr
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind    0 jun 30 20:45 myFile.jar
drwxrwxr-x 4 rinzwind rinzwind 4096 jun 30 20:51 hexara
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ ls -ltr hexara/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 rinzwind rinzwind 4096 jun 30 20:51 WSL
drwxrwxr-x 2 rinzwind rinzwind 4096 jun 30 20:51 VSL
```

and after the move ...

```
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ mv myFile.jar hexara/*
```

VSL is moved too:

```
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ ls -ltr hexara/
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 rinzwind rinzwind 4096 jun 30 20:52 WSL
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ ls -ltr hexara/WSL/
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind    0 jun 30 20:45 myFile.jar
drwxrwxr-x 2 rinzwind rinzwind 4096 jun 30 20:51 VSL
```

requiring more repairs.

Comment: I was inspecting my CLI record more closely and just noticed that everything that was in the hexara folder was moved into VSL. This makes no sense to me, but it matches what you describe in your answer. If I am in /tmp and execute `mv myFile.jar hexara/*`, why would the contents of /tmp/hexara all be moved into /tmp/hexara/VSL?

Comment: @PhilFreihofner the `*`  will get expanded to  `mv myFile.jar hexara/VSL hexara/WSL`  so all files end up in the last directory.

Comment: I see. OK that makes really good sense. Thank you so much. Wish I could upvote twice!

Comment: Without wishing to sound patronising, it is a good illustration of why you have to be careful with using wildcards that are expanded by the shell - the shell sometimes expands things in unexpected ways if you're not expert ... I avoid using wildcards unless I'm very sure it will do what I want.  Nice question and answer, got me experimenting on the CLI to reproduce it and learn something - thank you both!

Comment: Thank you Will. Very diplomatically put, too.